# Access external jwksuri behind a company proxy

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I am new to istio and had doubt configuring a Request authentication policy.The policy uses a jwksuri which is an external URI.The policy is applied on the istio-system namespace.The moment I apply this policy and do

```
>istioctl proxy-status
```

The ingress gateway on which the policy is applied LDS is marked stale.If I remove this policy the gateway goes back into SYNCED state.It seems this jwksuri is not accessible since we are behind a company proxy. I created Service entry to access the external jwks uri something like this

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: 
networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
name: jwksexternal
 spec:
  hosts:
  - 
authorization.company.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
EOF
```

Also tried to create one more service entry "Configuring traffic to external proxy" referring to this documentation https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/http-proxy/

But this is not working.How should I configure the company proxy in Istio.

**Edit this is the logs in istiod (Please note https://authorization.company.com/jwk is an external url)**

```
2021-06-02T14:35:39.423938Z error model Failed to fetch public key from "https://authorization.company.com/jwk": Get "https://authorization.company.com/jwk": dial tcp: lookup authorization.company.com on 10.X.0.X:53: no such host
2021-06-02T14:35:39.423987Z error Failed to fetch jwt public key from "https://authorization.company.com/jwk": Get "https://authorization.company.com/jwk": dial tcp: lookup authorization.company.com on 10.X.0.X:53: no such host
2021-06-02T14:35:39.424917Z info ads LDS: PUSH for node:istio-ingressgateway-5b69b5448c-8wbt4.istio-system resources:1 size:4.5kB
2021-06-02T14:35:39.433976Z warn ads ADS:LDS: ACK ERROR router~10.X.48.X~istio-ingressgateway-5b69b5448c-8wbt4.istio-system~istio-system.svc.cluster.local-105 Internal:Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_8443: Provider 'origins-0' in jwt_authn config has invalid local jwks: Jwks RSA [n] or [e] field is missing or has a parse error
```

Not able to find a workaround for this issue. As of now embedded the jwks into the jwt rules.But this has a problem ,whenever the public key keys get rotated .The jwt rules fail. This is a proxy issue but not sure how to bypass

Answer (score 1):

By default, Istio allows traffic to external systems.

See https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#change-to-the-blocking-by-default-policy

So if the problem is that the JWKS URL can't be accessed, it is most likely not because of Istio and a ServiceEntry won't help. I guess the problem will be somewhere else, not in Istio.

Comment: I get the following in the istiod logs      2021-06-02T02:51:54.948646Z error Failed to fetch jwt public key from "https://authorization.company.com/jwk": Get "https://authorization.company.com/jwk": dial tcp: lookup authorization.company.com on 10.X.0.X:53: no such host

Comment: The host in your ServiceEntry shouldn't contain a path (so should be without /jwks)

Comment: Sorry my bad the service entry is without the "jwks in path" .

Comment: Not able to find a workaround for this issue. As of now embedded the jwks into the jwt rules.But this has a problem ,whenever the public key keys get rotated .The jwt rules fail. This is a proxy issue but not sure how to bypass

Comment: Same issue for me... there must be some way.  To me it seems istiod needs to be told to use proxy.  I tried to edit the istiod deployment with kubectl and add the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY, but that resulted in errors trying to access internal services on 10.* & adding that in NO_PROXY didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me is running below which invokes `istioctl` to update proxy env params in istiod pods.  Once I did it, it faced issues talking to 10.96.0.1 and adding that in NO_PROXY fixed that.  Now it's able to pull keys from external jwks_uri & complete JWT auth (NOTE: I also added istio ServiceEntry for my proxy and jwks hosts... didn't test removing it yet, but I think they are required)

```
echo '
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    pilot:
      k8s:
        env:
        - name: HTTPS_PROXY
          value: "http://youproxy.com:8080"
        - name: NO_PROXY
          value: "10.96.0.1"
' | istioctl install -y -f -
```